# Creating a new random list from a source list

Tags: .net, vb.net, algorithm, list, random

I am using VB.net 2012 and am wanting to do the following in code:

I have a list of media items that is of length x.
Each item in the list has a duration of y.
I am wanting to create a new random list that has a total duration of z, and the items can only appear once in this new list.

What is the best way to do this? I am not sure if this qualifies as a 'rucksack problem.' Either way, may I please have some help to achieve this, either with pseudo code or actual vb.net code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
1. Object Song: properties Name, Duration
2. mlstLibrary = List(Of Song) ... fill mlstLibrary
3. user enters desired playlist duration intPlaylistDuration    
4. make a copy of mlstLibrary called mlstLibraryWorking
5. Dim intPlaylistDurationWorking As Integer = 0
6. Dim lstPlaylist As New List(Of Song) ' This is the output playlist
7. Do While mlstLibraryWorking.Count > 0
7a.  Go through mlstLibraryWorking and remove all items that have .Duration > (intPlaylistDuration - intPlaylistDurationWorking)
7b1.  Pick random Song from mlstLibraryWorking 
7b2.  Add selected Song to mlstPlaylist
7b3.  intPlaylistDurationWorking += selected Song.Duration
7b4.  Remove selected Song from mlstLibraryWorking  
8. Loop
```

Comment: EDITED: Had the wrong sign (< instead of >) at step 7a. Obviously, you should remove all songs that have a duration greater than the remaining amount of playlist time.

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding you, but it seems you have list `l` of pairs `(item,x)` and you want to find a subset of `l` (let it be `l'`) such that `sum(l'.e.item) == z`.

Unfortunately - you are describing the [**Subset Sum Problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), so **there is no known polynomial solution for it**.

If the list is fairly small you can use brute force (check all possibility). There is also [DP solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution) that runs in pseudo-polynomial time if the numbers are all integers.

Some alternatives are approximation algorithms or heuristics - such as [Genetic Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm).

Comment: The numbers are all positive integers. However, I do not want the sum to be 0... I am wanting the sum to be z that is a positive integer. Can the DP solution be used for this situation?

Comment: @user1843680 Though the vlassic subset sum is looking for sum 0, you.can get the variation by adding a "dummy" element too the list with value=-z. It is easy to see that the solution for the original is the same for the sum 0 problem with exception of the extra element.